# Fluent Bit: Logstash_Prefix_Key is not working as expected with 'es' output plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent-bit

I am trying to lookup a key from a record and use it as logstash prefix in fluent bit. But that's not happening and `Logstash_Prefix` is not being replaced by `Logstash_Prefix_Key` even though the specified key exists in the enriched log from `kubernetes` filter.

The ideal behaviour of a kubernetes filter is to enrich the logs read from input path via `input` plugin with kubernetes data such as pod name, pod id, namespace name etc. And when the logs after applying the filter is pushed to output source via `es` output plugin. I used `Logstash_Prefix_Key` to get the key `kubernetes.pod_name` and gave `Logstash_Prefix` as `pod_name`. Even though I'm able to see `kubernetes.pod_name` key in Kibana, the logs are getting stored in the prefix `pod_name` (which means `Logstash_Prefix_Key` is not found tn log records so it uses `Logstash_Prefix`).

Code sample

```
input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     2GB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
        Merge_Log           Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On

  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           kube.*
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
        HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
        Logstash_Format On
        Logstash_Prefix pod_name
        Logstash_Prefix_Key kubernetes.pod_name
        Retry_Limit     False
```

Since I am new to EFK stack, Could someone help me with this

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**: it's now supported! https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/421#issuecomment-766912018
Should be in Fluent Bit v1.7 release!

---

Dynamic ElasticSearch indexes are not supported in FluentBit at the moment. Here's a related issue: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/421. You can only specify a string (hardcoded) prefixes.

The workaround is to use a fluentd log collector instead, which supports dynamic indexes: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch#index_name-optional. There's a community chart for it: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/fluentd

UPD: it's now supported! https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/421#issuecomment-766912018
Should be in Fluent Bit v1.7 release!

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to do the same recently and though what Max Lobur said above is true about fluentbit not having support for this prior to the not yet released version 1.7. However, I was still able to achieve this with the current version using the `nest` filter, see https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch .under the `Logstash_Prefix_Key` it says

> When included: the value in the record that belongs to the key will be looked up and over-write the Logstash_Prefix for index generation. If the key/value is not found in the record then the Logstash_Prefix option will act as a fallback. Nested keys are not supported (if desired, you can use the nest filter plugin to remove nesting)

The last sentence is about nested keys not supported however you can still use them if you use the nest filter to lift them up a level.

In your case the pod_name is nested under kubernetes, to still be able to use it, you would have to lift it out of that level. see [nest example here](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/nest#example-1-nest-and-lift-undo).

Here's how to make it work in your case:

```
filter-kubernetes.conf: |
[FILTER]
    Name                kubernetes
    Match               kube.*
    Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
    Merge_Log           Off
    K8S-Logging.Parser  On

[FILTER]
    Name                nest
    Match               *
    Operation           lift
    Nested_under        kubernetes
    Add_prefix          kubernetes_

output-elasticsearch.conf: |
[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           kube.*
    Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
    Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
    HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
    HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix pod_name
    Logstash_Prefix_Key kubernetes_pod_name
    Retry_Limit     False
```

what we are doing here is lifting everything inside the kubernetes object up a level and prefixing them with kubernetes_, so your `pod_name` will become `kubernetes_pod_name`. You then pass the `kubernetes_pod_name` to `Logstash_prefix_key`. The value of `kubernetes_pod_name` is then use for index generation and would only resort back to `logstash_prefix` if no key/value pair exist for the `kubernetes_pod_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Logstash_Prefix_Key kubernetes['pod_name']
```

This is working on my machine using the docker image: `fluent/fluent-bit:1.7`